# compact set $K$ is called the support of $\mu$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a regular Borel measure on a compact Hausdorff topological space $X$. (Here, a measure is *Borel* if it is defined on a Borel $\sigma$-algebra.) If $\mu(X)=1$, prove that there exists a compact set $K\subset X$ such that $\mu(K)=1$, but $\mu(H)<1$ for every proper compact subset $H$ of $K$. Such a compact set $K$ is called the *support* of $\mu$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to proof this by using Riesz representation theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Riesz Representation would be overkill.

I'll reason with open sets, since I personally find it a bit clearer, you can just take complements throughout and get what you want.

Let $\tau$ be the topology on $X$ and $\mathscr F$ the collection of closed subsets of $X$. Define
$$
U:=\bigcup\{V\in\tau :\mu(V)=0\}
$$
Of course, $U$ is open, so $K:=X\setminus U$ is closed, thus compact (because $X$ is compact).

We show that $\mu(U)=0$. Suppose otherwise, so $\mu(U)>0$, and we can find $F\in\mathscr F$ with $F\subset U$ and $\mu(F)>0$. For each $x\in F$, fix $V_x\in\tau$ with $x\in V_x$ and $\mu(V_x)=0$. This is possible by $F\subset U$. Since $F$ is compact, we can pick $x_1,\dots,x_n\in F$ with $F\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{x_i}$. But then $\mu(F)\le \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(V_{x_i})=0$, contradiction.

The last statement to be shown is equivalent to $\mu(W)>0$ for every open set $W\supsetneq U$. But this is clear, because $\mu(W)=0$ for $W\in\tau$ immediately implies $W\subset U$ (since $W$ is one of the things being "unioned" to form $U$).